# In Neovim with Treesitter, most of the text appears in italic style

Tags: neovim, treesitter, neovim-plugin

I'm using Treesitter in Neovim for code highlighting, but most of my code highlights appear as italic. I've encountered some GitHub issues related to this problem, which can be found here: [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/issues/3396).

I suspect this might be a mistake on my part rather than a bug in Treesitter. I'm just trying to set up a simple Neovim configuration.

Could this issue be related to running Neovim on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)?

Here's an example of what my code looks like:
[image: Italic Treesitter]

And here's my Treesitter.lua configuration:

```
require'nvim-treesitter.configs'.setup {
    -- A list of parser names, or "all"
    ensure_installed = { "lua", "c", "javascript", "vimdoc", "rust" },

    -- Install parsers synchronously (only applied to `ensure_installed`)
    sync_install = false,

    -- Automatically install missing parsers when entering a buffer
    -- Recommendation: set to false if you don't have the `tree-sitter` CLI installed locally
    auto_install = true,

    highlight = {
        -- `false` will disable the whole extension
        enable = true,

        -- Setting this to true will run `:h syntax` and tree-sitter at the same time.
        -- Set this to `true` if you depend on 'syntax' being enabled (like for indentation).
        -- Using this option may slow down your editor, and you may see some duplicate highlights.
        -- Instead of true, it can also be a list of languages
        additional_vim_regex_highlighting = false,
    },
}
```

I'm using Neovim version:

- NVIM v0.10.0-dev-1451+g20dd9f3a2
- Build type: Release
- LuaJIT 2.1.1697887905

Comment: This problem is not caused by your TreeSitter configuration but it's defined (use of italic style for some keywords) by your `colorscheme`. What is your colorscheme (see `:colorscheme` command) ?

Comment: Your are right, ty! I used rose pine. After I switched everything worked out fine. @lcheylus